# Get settings with the help of enum VB.NET

Tags: java, .net, vb.net, enums

I'm translating a Java program to vb.net where settings in the application is controlled by a enum.

```
    private enum SmsTagRule {
    //      KEYWORD   DOMAIN    BusinessClass  PREFIX  SEARCHNAME   SEARCHPARAM  SENDEMAIL  KEYWORDS...
    BAG_TAG("BagTag", "BagTag", "FoundBagTag", "b", "SearchBagTag", "490_TagNumber", true, "BagTag"),
    SKI_TAG("SkiTag", "SkiTag", "FoundSkiTag", "a", "SearchSki", "518_LabelNo", false, "SkiTag", "ski"),
    PC_TAG("PcTag", "ds", "FoundPC", "", "SearchPcTag", "585_LabelNo", false, "pc");
```

And depending on witch "TAG" in chosen different settings are getting returned. Is there any way to do this in vb.NET. I have thought about creating one enum for each one of these TAG's but it seems like it should be a better solution to this.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go on and create a custom Type representing your settings:

```
Class TagRule

    Public Shared BAG = new TagRule("BagTag", "BagTag", "FoundBagTag", ...)
    Public Shared Ski = new TagRule("SkiTag", "SkiTag", "FoundSkiTag", ...)
    ...

    Dim _keyword As String
    Public Property Keyword as String
        Public Get
            return _keyword         
        End 
        Private Set
            _keyword = value
        End
    End Property

    ...

    Private Sub New(keyword as String, domain as String, businessclass as String, ...)
        _keyword = keyword
        _domain = domain
        ....
    End Sub

End Class
```

And you can use it like this:

```
Dim setting As TagRule = Nothing

If somecondition Then
    setting = TagRule.Ski
Else
    setting = TagRule.BAG
End If

Dim keyword = setting.Keyword
Dim domain = setting.Domain
```